# How ton implement a not regexp_like() in datastage

Tags: datastage

I working on migration and I would like to implement this expression on datastage (transformer) :
not regexp_like(column,'^[[:digit]]+$')

thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for REGEX in the Transformer stage.  One solution would be to use the Data Rules stage (if you have it), which does have a MATCHES_REGEX operator.
Another solution would be to use a BASIC Transformer stage, which has a Matches operator (though it uses a syntax other than regex; you'd need something like `column Matches "0N'+'`)